# Gmail app on mobile - SMTP settings?

Tags: gmail, imap, smtp

I cannot find what IMAP/SMTP settings are used when connecting to a Gmail account on the Gmail application on mobile (Android).

Is there any way to find them ? What settings are in use by default ?

I'm trying to figure out if it uses IMAPS and SMTPS (not StartTLS).

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=el

Comment: This answers the IMAP part, but not the SMTP part. It could be using StartTLS or TLS for SMTP.